Cross-compile Qt5 with CMake: qt5 Qt5MultimediaConfig.cmake search lib is a absolute path
i use mount make target lib mount on /mnt ,and use CMAKE_SYSROOT make sysroot as /mnt path .
then i try to cross compile, cmake throw a error massage:
....
 "/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtMultimedia"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
...

i suppose qt config file is absolute path. and i find QtMultimediaConfig.cmake file...
The ideal situation path is /mnt/**** ,but there is a absolute path:
get_filename_component(_realOrig "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Gui" REALPATH)
if(_realCurr STREQUAL _realOrig)
    get_filename_component(_qt5Gui_install_prefix "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/../../" ABSOLUTE)
else()
    get_filename_component(_qt5Gui_install_prefix "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../"

i try to change the absolute path ,don't know how to solve the problem

have also tried the apt multi-arch. also encountered problem, can't install opencv
